# Upload video along with thumbnail - YouTube Data API Python

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to use the YouTube API to upload a video and thumbnail together.

I implemented the code sample for uploading the video, and it works perfectly (https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/upload_video.py).

How can I upload a thumbnail along with the video?

Comment: what have you tried? where have you got stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer to your question is negative.

This happens because the [`Videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) API endpoint does not allow one to upload two things at once (that video's content and its thumbnail).

For to attach a thumbnail to an already existing (thus already uploaded) video, you'll have to use another API endpoint: [`Thumbnails.set`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set).

For what concerns Python, I'd recommend to read, understand and use the public sample code from Google: [`upload_thumbnail.py`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/upload_thumbnail.py).